# Converting trigonometric expressions between sine and cosine forms

Tags: replacement, trigonometry

How to convert sine and cosine into each other?

Using the relationship between sine and cosine for mutual transformation:

[image]

Such as:

```
Sqrt[3] Sin[π/6 - (π x)/4]
```

Convert the sine above to cosine as:

```
Sqrt[3] Cos[π/3 + (π x)/4]
```

Also,Convert the cosine above to sine as:

```
Sqrt[3] Sin[π/6 - (π x)/4]
```

And so on

Comment: `r1 = Sin[θ_] -> Inactive[Cos][π/2 - θ // Expand]; and Sqrt[3] Sin[π/6 - (π x)/4] /. r1`. You can add `//Activate` if you wish to let Mathematica finish the evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
coswitch = {
   Sin -> (Cos[Pi/2 - # // Simplify] &), 
   Cos -> (Sin[Pi/2 - # // Simplify] &)};
expr = Sqrt[3]  Sin[\[Pi]/6 - (\[Pi]  x)/4];
expr /. coswitch

(* Sqrt[3] Cos[1/12 \[Pi] (4 + 3 x)] *)

% /. coswitch

(* Sqrt[3] Sin[1/12 \[Pi] (2 - 3 x)] *)
```